# SQL Connection from Azure Linux App Service web app

Tags: sql-server, linux, azure, asp.net-core, connection

I have an asp net core web app and SQL Server database hosted in Plesk via a hosting company.

I have deployed a copy of the web app to an Azure Linux App Service. It uses the Plesk hosted SQL Server database. When i use the Azure App Service I get a connection error when accessing the Plesk hosted database.

**SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)**

If I use the Plesk hosted web app it connects to sql server correctly as expected. If I then immediately use the Azure Linux web app it manages to get a SQL connection!  In all cases the connection string is identical. Its like it needs waking up!

How can this be the case. I am at a loss as to why this is happens. Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 1):

Properly, you need to add the [outbound IP addresses in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#find-outbound-ips) into the firewall of SQL Server which your SQL Server database existed.

### edit

You could check the following aspects on your side refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b43775b9-cd96-4f14-bd1e-b40172c5fc83/a-networkrelated-or-instancespecific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server).

> 1. Make sure SQL Server Service is running
> 2. If a named instance, make sure SQL Server browser service is running
> 3. Make sure SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections
> 4. Examine the SQL Server error log for messages confirming that SQL is listening on the expected network interfaces and ports
> 5. Test server connectivity with PING from the client machine
> 6. Test port connectivity using TELNET or PowerShell to the server and port (from step 4) from the client machine.  For example a. TELNET
>     1433 b. PowerShell: 1433 | % { echo ((new-object
>    Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect("YourServerName",$*)) "server listening
>    on TCP port $*" }
> 7. Check firewall settings if step 5 or 6 connectivity test fails

For more information:

- [Troubleshoot connecting to the SQL Server Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Networking Related Commands for Azure App Services](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-app-service/networking-related-commands-for-azure-app-services/ba-p/392410)

Comment: Plesk hosting say there is no blocking of connections so not needed

Comment: I have a screenshot of the web page working but that is a 1 in 10 chance with nothing being changed by me. I also have a Windows App Service plan and the identical code from that connects to the SAL database without issue.

Comment: It looks like a server-side error. Check if your DB server is running and your type the correct server name or parameters when you connect. You could go to the console from your  Linux app service to troubleshoot it.